# Excluding of a package in a library .jar

Tags: android, gradle

I am importing a library, that clashes with another library (there are two same classes). How can I exclude the package with the classes from the .jar in Gradle?

```
dependencies {

//final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '24.0.0'

final RETROFIT_VERSION = '2.0.0'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
.
.
.
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0')

compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0") {
    exclude 'firebase' directory in here
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't exclude individual things within a dependency.  All Gradle does is hand over the Jars to Java(c), nothing more.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's a pity. What to do if there are two libraries with some absolutely identical classes? Firebase and Google play services is a good example.

Comment: That's a difficult problem.  But excluding individual classes (even if it were possible) wouldn't solve the problem - what if that class is in turn depended on by another class in that library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I close this question, because it's no more relevant.

As Oliver Charlesworth commented, it's very difficult to solve.

In my case, there was a problem with `FirebaseException` class, which was doubled - once in `Google Play Services` library, once in `Firebase` library. It was my mistake, I forgot to increase the Firebase library version number (it was 9.0.0.), so that it did not match with GPS 9.4.0. That's all.